# Taylor series expansion of arctan(x) around the point 0

Tags: taylor-expansion, wolfram-alpha

This is actually a technical question about why I'm getting different results when trying to do the same thing using Maxima and WolframAlpha.

When I enter

> expand arctan(x)

in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20arctan%28x%29) I get

$$x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^9}{9}+O(x^{10})$$

This is what I enter into maxima to get the 5th degree expansion for example

> ff:taylor(arctan(x),x,0,5);

The result is littered with terms containing derivative symbols, unlike the nice-looking polynomial WolframAlpha returns.

My question is how to get Maxima to evaluate the expansion at the point 0 and return the first polynomial?

Comment: Repeated differentiation of $\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ and evaluation at $x=0$ won't give a $1$. Try it. The second derivative of $\arctan x$ is $0$ at $0$. The third derivative is $-2$ at $x=0$.

Comment: I don't have maxima, and you haven't shown what its output is.  But maybe "arctan" is not known to it... perhaps "atan" or something is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maxima uses that name `atan`, not *arctan*. Thus `taylor(atan(x), x, 0, 9)` will give you the same result as Wolfram Alpha. When you use arctan, Maxima simply returns the generic Taylor expansion of an *unknown function*, hence all the derivatives.

You can execute `alias(arctan, atan)`, if you wish to use the arctan as an alias to the built-in atan.